# LIST to data.frame in XML file

Tags: r, xml, list

I am working on XML files and I am trying to transform them into data.frame. However, during the transformation process the file is `“LIST”`, as seen below:

My Code:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(xml2)
page<-read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<test2:TASS xmlns="http://www.vvv.com/schemas"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vvv.com/schemas http://www.vvv.com/schemas/testV2_02_03.xsd"  
xmlns:test2="http://www.vvv.com/schemas" >
                <test2:billing>
                    <test2:proceduresummary>
                        <test2:guidenumber>Z4088</test2:guidenumber>
                            <test2:diagnosis>
                                <test2:table>ICD-10</test2:table>
                                <test2:diagnosiscod>G93</test2:diagnosiscod>
                                <test2:description>DISORDER OF BRAIN, UNSPECIFIED</test2:description>
                            </test2:diagnosis>
                            <test2:procedure>
                                <test2:procedure>
                                    <test2:description>HOSPITAL</test2:description>
                                </test2:procedure>
                                <test2:amount>15</test2:amount>
                            </test2:procedure>
                    </test2:proceduresummary>
                </test2:billing>
</test2:TASS>')


t1<-if ("test2" %in%  names(xml_ns(page))) {
  ns<-xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(page), test2 = "test")
} else {
  ns<- xml_ns(page)
}


MYFILE<- ifelse(names(xml_ns(page)) %in% "d1",
            page %>% xml_find_all(".//d1:billing"),
            page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing", ns))


MYFILE<-xml2::as_list(MYFILE) %>% jsonlite::toJSON() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

My "LIST"

```
**List of 1
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ node:<externalptr> 
  ..$ doc :<externalptr> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "xml_node"**
```

I'm using the code below to transform it, but it's giving an error:

```
MYFILE <- xml2 :: as_list (MYFILE)%>% jsonlite :: toJSON ()%>% jsonlite :: fromJSON ()
```

This is the error.

```
Error in UseMethod("as_list") : 
  no applicable method for 'as_list' applied to an object of class "list"
```

How do I turn it into data.frame/tibble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `ifelse` statement is causing the file to be parsed three times.  This is causing a problem.  If you need this line try this instead `ifelse("d1" %in% names(xml_ns(page)), . . .`

This script works on the above sample.  If there are more than 1 billing node then part of the below script will need modification. I highlighted that in the comments.

```
t1<-if ("test2" %in%  names(xml_ns(page))) {
  ns<-xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(page), test2 = "test")
} else {
  ns<- xml_ns(page)
}

MYFILE<- ifelse(names(xml_ns(page)) %in% "d1",
            page %>% xml_find_all(".//d1:billing"),
            page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing", ns))

#To prevent repeating reading the file multiple times
# MYFILE<- if ("d1" %in% names(xml_ns(page))) {
# page %>% xml_find_all(".//d1:billing")
# } else { 
# page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing", ns)
# }

OUTPUT<-lapply(MYFILE, function(MYFILE){
 #convert all of the nodes to named vector
 output<-as_list(MYFILE)  %>% unlist()

 #Shorten the names
 names(output) <-  gsub("^(.+?\\.)", "", names(output))

 #depending on your next steps will determine the disired output
 #create a long format dataframe
# long_answer<-data.frame(Name=names(output), output, row.names = NULL)

 #create a wide format dataframe
 wide_answer<-data.frame( t(output))
})

bind_rows(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Thanks. As my files follow more than one pattern I have to do this part (ifelse (names (xml_ns (page))% in% "d1", etc ....). In addition, the error is appearing: Error in UseMethod (" as_list "):
   no applicable method for 'as_list' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: When I put OUTPUT <-lapply (MYFILE, function (MYFILE) {
  output <-as_list (MYFILE)%>% unlist () the function appears to be incomplete.

Comment: Make sure you copy the entire segment, there are 3 lines of code in the function.

Comment: You are very good. I will probably post more questions about XML files. I'm having a lot of difficulty due to the lack of a pattern in my files. Thanks !!

Comment: As I said, my files have no pattern. How would it be, for example, to select the first 20 columns of "OUTPUT"? I would like this selection to be within the function. It is possible?

Comment: The last line of the function creates the data frame "wide_answer". So yes you could modify/filter this data frame before exiting the function.  For example the last line could be `wide_answer[, 1:20]` to return the first 20 columns.

Comment: Suppose I have one more element in MYFILE <- if ("d1"% in% names (xml_ns (page))) {........ that is "d1" and "d2" ... How it would look my expression? That is, I will have 3 elements to evaluate: d1, d2 and test.

Comment: You have a couple of options the "if, else if and else" construct.  Or possibly the "switch()" function or even "dplyr::case_when()"